# Why is the wrong field value shown in the error message when using jQuery (remote) validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin in a very similar manner to the [Remember The Milk demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/).

```
$("#registrationForm").validate({
  rules: {      
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: '<%=Url.Action(...) %>'
    },        
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "Please enter an email address",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address",
      remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
    }
});
```

The first time an invalid email (e.g. bob@mail.com) is submitted, the error message is as expected. However, if I then enter another invalid email (e.g. sue@mail.com), the validation plugin still displays "bob@mail.com is already in use."

I've traced the parameters that are reaching the controller specified in `Url.Action` call and they are definitely correct (i.e. "sue@mail.com" is sent as the email address when that is what is entered in the field).

Has anyone else run into this or a similar issue using the jQuery validation plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user name field on the Remember the Milk demo fails in the same way (when entering user names 'Peter' and 'George'), so you've probably found a bug in the plugin.

Comment: Oh..thanks I wasn't sure which items I could use to test that to make the error happen with them.

Answer (score 2):

Over two years later and the bug still doesn't seem to be fixed, so here's what I found:

The issue is in the `remote` function:

```
remote: function(value, element, param) {
    if ( this.optional(element) )
        return "dependency-mismatch";

    var previous = this.previousValue(element);
    if (!this.settings.messages[element.name] )
        this.settings.messages[element.name] = {};
    previous.originalMessage = this.settings.messages[element.name].remote;
    this.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.message;

    // snip more code...
}
```

Trouble is that on the 2nd and later evaluations of this function, the `messages[element.name].remote` contains a specific (text) error message, and the *actual* original message is lost forever when `previous.originalMessage` is overwritten after that.

I was able to work around the issue by adding a check before that line:

```
if (!previous.originalMessage)
    previous.originalMessage = this.settings.messages[element.name].remote;
```

I'm not sure if this is really the *correct* solution, but it works - validation failures now reapply the format function on each validation failure.