# jQuery Validate: remote - user name won't change in error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

- I'm creating a signup form with Bassistance jQuery Validate plugin, checking if username is already in use.
- Everything works, if I fill in a username that is already in the database a message like 'xxxxxxx is already in use.' is shown.
- However, if I fill in another username that is already in use (eg. yyyyy) the message keeps saying 'xxxxxxx is already in use.'
- This behaviour is also present in the 'official' demo on http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/ - if i first fill in 'Peter', and after that I fill in 'George' the message keeps saying 'Peter is already in use'
- I was wondering if someone has found a fix for this?

My code:

`remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use.")`

Comment: A workaround for this bug was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9334819/470749

Answer (score 2):

Just looked through the jQuery Validate plugin code and they have a bug in their code where they cache error messages forever, which results in exactly what you're seeing.

You're little snippet of code is correct, they have a bug on their end.

Comment: could you post the link to this bug?