# jQuery Validator Plugin and Dialog - Value reflect only if the dialog is not closed

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-validate

**Am using jQuery Validation Plugin for Validation**

I have a user creation form for adding a new user to a database. When the user tries to add a new user, I will check the existence of user name in the DB and will return true or false, as the validator plugin just needs true or false.

Below is the code

```
remote : " {0} already exist ";
```

This code works absolutely fine the first time. If I give an existing Id say "user1", "user2", "user3". I will get

```
user 1 already exist
user 2 already exist
user 3 already exist
```

Subsequently.

When I close the dialog and reopen it again, it will always show a single way. Assume i repeat the same condition give above. The output will be

```
user 1 already exist
user 1 already exist
user 1 already exist
```

The **{0}**, given in the remote switch will replace the text given in the text box. Is it a dialog problem?

Code :

```
$("#login").rules("add",{
    remote : {
    type : "GET",
    url : <ServletURL>,
    cache : false,
    async : false
    }
});
```

This is what I use in the custom message

```
login:  {
        remote   : jQuery.format("{0} already exist")
  },
```

Comment: Can you post your JS Code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the answer in StackOverflow itself.

This question is indirectly answered here and it seems to be a BUG in jQuery Validation Plugin

[Why is the wrong field value shown in the error message when using jQuery (remote) validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626998/why-is-the-wrong-field-value-shown-in-the-error-message-when-using-jquery-remot/9334819#9334819)